# How can I combine JS Object Literal with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I'm cleaning up my JS code and want to create namespaces and use JS OO. I found a very god [tutorial by Rebecca Murphey](http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/10/15/using-objects-to-organize-your-code/) on Object Literal pattern.

Now I'm wondering how I can use this to achieve e.g. jQuery UI autocomplete by writing:

```
// Pseudocode
$('#input_field').myNameSpace.my_search();

var myNameSpace= {
  my_search : function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({...});
  },

  my_other_function: function() {}
};
```

Currently I'm using my own plugin:

```
$('#input_field').my_search();


(function ($) {
  $.fn.my_search = function () {

    $(this).autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
      source: function( request, response ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: callback_url,
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
              return {
                id: item.id,
                value: item.name,
                name_encoded: item.name_encoded
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        (...)
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Any help appreciated.

**update**
My first example was pretty close and James Kyburz was also very close (but working). I've simplified James's answer to avoid a complicated return data.

```
(function () {
  // Namspace which also kind of works like an interface
  $.fn.my_name_space = function(opt) {
    this.autosuggest_brand = autosuggest.autosuggest_brand;
    return this;
  }

  var autosuggest = {
    autosuggest_brand : function(action) {
      $(this).autocomplete({
        // Autocomplete stuff here
      });
    },
    som_other_function _ function() {}
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still trying but don't think it's possible

One way would be to wrap everything in a function be it not a namespace...

```
$.fn.my_namespace = function() {
  var el = this;
  var foo = function() { console.log('foo', el); };
  var bar = function() { console.log('bar', el); };
  return { foo: foo, bar: bar };
}

$('input:first').my_namespace().foo() // foo, [input...]
$('input:first').my_namespace().bar() // bar, [input...]
```

Unless you need to support old browsers using defineProperty might be a solution

```
Object.defineProperty($.fn, 'my_namespace', {
  get: function() {
    var el = this;
    return {
      foo: function() { console.log( 'foo', el); },
      bar: function() { console.log( 'bar', el); },
    }
  }
});

$('input:first').my_namespace.foo() // foo, [input...]
$('input:first').my_namespace.bar() // bar, [input...]
```

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the code a bit (see my update) in order to avoid having a long return "string". Is there a way I could use `.storelocator.autosuggest();` instead of `.storelocator().autosuggest();` ?

Comment: @Steven I haven't found away except by using defineProperty

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use namespaces for jQuery plugins (or only very complicated - the [context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) of the selection is lost when you execute the `.my_search()` method *on the namespace object*).

Your current plugin is fine; if you want namespacing then use prefixes like `namespace_search`.

Comment: Thanks @bergi. James lead me on to a workable (workaround?) solution. See my update.

Comment: @Steven: Yes, that's what I meant with "very complicated". Your update that uses `return this.extend(search)` to introduce new methods on a particular instance is quite interesting, but imho misses the point of "namespace" a littlebit :-)

Comment: I know :) But it's the closest I got to bundle my functions. I've done a new update and you can see how I use autoselect for different purposes. Currently I'm stuck on how I can clear the input field after selecting from the autoselect. Any tips appreciated.